# .NET Core Consumer Kafka error deadlock SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, microservices, kafka-consumer-api, asp.net-core-5.0

I am new to .NET. I have micro services using .NET Core. This service is used to become a Kafka consumer. In the consumer function there is a function to insert into the SQL Server database. This function often experiences `deadlock` errors, but sometime when traffic is low this code work with no error. I attached the function code. This function is simple, just to insert into the database using the transaction `set identity insert on`. Please help if anyone has experienced something like this. The error looks like this.

```
An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Entities.RepositoryContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 414) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

```
    private async Task insertData(Dto data)
    {
        var dataFromDB = _repository.myRepo.FirstOrDefaultWithNoLock(p => p.ID.Equals(data.ID));

        if (dataFromDB == null)
        {
            dataFromDB = _mapper.Map<Model>(data);
            _repository.myRepo.Create(dataFromDB);
            _repository.myRepo.SaveChangesWithIdentityInsert();
            return;
        }

        return;
    }
```

I attached code inside `SaveChangesWithIdentityInsert`

```
        public static void EnableIdentityInsert<T>(this DbContext context) => SetIdentityInsert<T>(context, true);
        public static void DisableIdentityInsert<T>(this DbContext context) => SetIdentityInsert<T>(context, false);

        private static void SetIdentityInsert<T>([NotNull] DbContext context, bool enable)
        {
            if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
            var value = enable ? "ON" : "OFF";
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.{entityType.GetTableName()} {value}");
        }

        public static void SaveChangesWithIdentityInsert<T>([NotNull] this DbContext context)
        {
            if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            var strategy = context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            strategy.Execute(
            () =>
            {
                using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel: System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
                context.EnableIdentityInsert<T>();
                context.SaveChanges();
                context.DisableIdentityInsert<T>();
                transaction.Commit();
            });
            context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
        }
```

I have try to use `with no lock`. I have searching to auto retry consumer when deadlock occur but not found anything.

Comment: What is in this method `SaveChangesWithIdentityInsert()`? also post this deadlock error/exception.

Comment: It's a myth that `WITH (NOLOCK)` takes no locks - at a minimum it takes and holds Sch-M locks.

Comment: @DenisMicheal I edited the question, i have attahced savechangeswithidentityinsert

Comment: @FirmanAlam the problems are caused by all this unnecessary code. DbContext has no need for CRUD classes named "repository", it's a higher level abstraction, a Unit-of-Work. `SaveChangesWithIdentityInsert` tries to do what SaveChanges itself would do for *all* modified objects, and does so in a very buggy way that causes blocking by explicitly wrapping `SaveChanges` in yet another transaction

Comment: `FirstOrDefaultWithNoLock` is pointless too, because DbContext isn't a database connection. It doesn't even open a connection unless it has to read or write data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can u explain more, what i have to do?

Comment: Are you sure it is a database deadlock? Have you checked deadlock graph in this case?

Comment: @NikitaChayka i have added the error log